# Integral on phase space

Tags: standard-model, scattering, phase-space, beyond-the-standard-model, scattering-cross-section

I'd like to integrate the square amplitude in the phase space( in $d^3k/(2\pi)^3 2E_k$ and $d^3k'/(2\pi)^3 2E_k$) where $p$ and $p'$ are the 4-momentum of the input particles, $k$ and $k'$ 4-momentum of output particles and $q$ the 4-momentum of the exchange particle. Have any suggestions?

$|A|^2 \propto \frac{1}{q^4}[-q\cdot k' q\cdot p' k\cdot p - 2 q \cdot k' q \cdot p k \cdot p'$ + ...
the difficulty I find is in the product $q \cdot k'$ (for example). How do I integrate in $d^3k'$ ? What useful relations can I use to simplify the calculations?

Comment: Use [Latex](https://physics.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex) direct formatting of formulas instead of embedded images.

Answer (score 0):

As you have tagged the standard model and scattering I assume what you are talking about is scatting in the $\phi^\dagger \psi \phi$ theory and you are familiar with concepts such as the [propagator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagator#Position_space). There are plenty of resources that cover this material such as [this one](https://academic.oup.com/book/36442?login=false).

You might want to read about the [the Feynman rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_diagram) to calculate the amplitudes. In your case the Feynman rules can be summarized as

- Each vertex contributes a factor $-ig$
- For each internal line carrying momentum $q$ you include a propator $\frac{i}{q^2-\mu^2+i\epsilon}$
- Integrate over all undetermined momenta. In your case you don't integrate over $q$ since it is completely determined by momentum conservation.
- Incoming and outgoing lines contribute a factor 1
- Symmetry factors are 1
- Include an overall energy-momentum conserving delta function for each diagram.

This means the amplitude for the second-order scattering diagrams is

$$
\mathcal{A}^{(2)}=(-ig)^2\frac{i}{q^2-\mu^2+i\epsilon}(2\pi)^4 \delta^{(4)}\left(\sum p_f -\sum p_i\right).
$$
For the three channels we have the following amplitudes

[t-channel](https://imgur.com/a/kjcDwwQ)
$$
\mathcal{A_t} = (-ig)^2\frac{i}{t-\mu^2+i\epsilon}(2\pi)^4 \delta^{(4)}\left(p'+k'-p-k\right), \quad q^2=(p'-p)^2=t
$$
[u-channel](https://imgur.com/a/SKAI3zw)
$$
\mathcal{A_u} = (-ig)^2\frac{i}{u-\mu^2+i\epsilon}(2\pi)^4 \delta^{(4)}\left(p'+k'-p-k\right), \quad q^2=(p'-k)^2=u
$$
[s-channel](https://imgur.com/a/hi9N6uq)
$$
\mathcal{A_s} = (-ig)^2\frac{i}{s-\mu^2+i\epsilon}(2\pi)^4 \delta^{(4)}\left(k+k'-p-p'\right), \quad q^2=(p+p')^2=s.
$$